# SPuser to find group membership

Tags: sharepoint, spuser

I have a code in which I have to check if a user is a part of a certain group (lets say "GroupA").

I have the user details stored in the Sharepoint variable SPUser. Now I need to check if this user is a part of GroupA and then take some action.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source :  [How to check if a user exists in a group](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1799/how-to-check-if-a-user-exists-in-a-group)

you can use following extension method, like this:

```
public static bool InGroup(this SPUser User, string GroupName)
{
    return User.Groups.Cast<SPGroup>().Any(g => g.Name.ToLower() == GroupName.ToLower());
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
bool inGroup = spuser.InGroup("GroupName");
```

If you want to check the current user then another approach can be like this:
From: [Check user already exist in specified SharePoint Group](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ta/sharepoint2010programming/thread/f18d51dd-8262-4460-8636-b6c6c1fb6866)

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPGroupCollection webGroups = web.Groups;

foreach (SPGroup group in webGroups)
{
 //Checking the group
 if (group.ContainsCurrentUser)
 {
  // perform action
 }
 else
 {
  //perform action
 }
}
```

For More Reference:

[Tell if user exists in SharePoint Group through web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881451/tell-if-user-exists-in-sharepoint-group-through-web-service)

Comment: That is a great approach! I am facing 1 small problem, even though a user is a part of the group I specify here, the condition is not evaluating to true.

I have tried using g.Name.Equals("Group Name", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) as well.